# Open pwd protected http stream in vlc from CLI

Tags: command-line, vlc

Can anyone please advise me on how to open a pwd protected http stream from CLI in vlc?

I checked out the --help and man pages, but they seem to offer only syntax for opening  ftp, rmt and smb pwd protected streams (and http-proxy), but not http. Or there is some walk around solution I am not thinking of?

What I have tried already:

```
cvlc http://192.168.1.67/videostream.asf?user=admin&pwd=XXX
cvlc http://user:XXX@192.168.1.67/videostream.asf
cvlc http://192.168.1.67/videostream.asf --http-user 'user' --http-pwd 'XXX'
```

---

May be I can not read the manuals properly but to me the instructions from vlc docs is really difficult to interpret into cli commands:

```
% vlc input_stream --sout "#module1{option1=parameter1{parameter-option1},option
2=parameter2}:module2{option1=...,option2=...}:..."

   You may also use the following syntax :
% vlc input_stream --sout-module1-option1=... --sout-module1-option2=... --sout-
module2-option1=... --sout-module2-option2=... ...

   For example, to transcode a stream and send it, use:
% vlc input_stream --sout '#transcode{options}:standard{options}'
```

If I have interpreted the manual correctly (so far I came up with 3 or 4 different options), I need module `standard`, option `access=`, then item `http:`, item options `user=<user name>` and  `pwd=<password>`. All put together should read one of these:

```
vlc http://192.168.1.67/videostream.asf '#standard{access=http:user=admin,pwd=XXX}'
vlc http://192.168.1.67/videostream.asf '#standard{access=http:user=admin},http:pwd=XXX}'
vlc http://192.168.1.67/videostream.asf --sout-standard-access=http:user=admin
```

(ok I did not put in the pwd in the last line but vlc did not even pick up the `user=`
 as user's name....).

But nothing works and I do not even get anywhere close to putting it right looking at the  output produced.

This is really cheeky and noobish but if someone could share a real working sample how that should look like, that would be greatly appreciated.

VERY IMPORTANT - I need a client part of the commands for capturing the stream...

---

Again, if I read the manual correctly, this part:

> http: **streams** over HTTP.
>          Item options are: user= to enable HTTP basic
>          authentication and set the user, pwd= to set the basic
>          authentication password, mime= to set the mime type
>          returned by the server.

is re the server part.

Comment: In your first attempt shouldn't it be ?user=admin&pwd=XXX?

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out. Unfortunately in was a typo only here, in CLI it was with the right syntax and still not working...

Answer (score 2):

From the client side just run

```
vlc http://YOURUSER:YOURPASSWD@192.168.1.67/videostream.asf
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

### • http: streams over HTTP

[**via Videolan-streaming-howto**](http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/streaming-howto-en.txt)

Item options are:
`user=<username>` to enable HTTP basic authentication and set the user.
`pwd=<password>` to set the basic authentication password.
`mime=<mime type>` to set the mime type returned by the server.

---

**Answer 2:**

### • mplayer

[**via man mplayer**](http://www.linuxmanpages.com/man1/mplayer.1.php)
mplayer is an alternative interface if your willing to try other packages.

With mplayer we have the following syntax available:
**`mplayer [mms[t]|http|http_proxy|rt[s]p|ftp]:// [user:passwd@]URL[:port] [options]`**

**`-user <user name>`**
    Specify user name for http authentication.

**`-passwd <password>`**
    Specify password for http authentication.

Please do note, I've unfortunately never used these options with mplayer before.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in this direction - but 'access' seems to be a server module from examples available on Videolan docs page (why auth commands though?????)